# sorting radio button list in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

How to sort a radio button list in ASP.NET? I need it to sort by Alphabetical order..

```
rblGeographicMandate.DataSource = lst;
rblGeographicMandate.DataTextField = "ChildName";
rblGeographicMandate.DataValueField = "ChildId";            
rblGeographicMandate.DataBind();
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> List<ValueValid> lst.. It is of List
>   type

Change it to a SortedList<ValueValid>

Answer (score 0):

What type is `lst`? 
If you have a sort method on the `lst` object, you can do that before binding, and you are good to go.

Comment: List<ValueValid> lst.. It is of List type